# sudo "Sorry try again" after changing username, group and home directory in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, sudo

I have a fresh Arch Linux VM which I just set up. Everything works great with it. `sudo` is also configured and works fine. Now I cloned my VM and changed the username and home directory of my normal user using these commands:

```bsh
su
usermod -d /home/newname -m oldname
usermod -l newname oldname
groupmod -n newname oldname
reboot
```

I also changed the passwords of all users (including root) using `passwd`.

The group name was the same as the user name. I got no errors, but after logging into my user I cannot use sudo anymore. I opened `/etc/sudoers` and changed

```
oldname ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
newname ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

and rebooted again. I still cannot use `sudo` anymore. It asks me for a password, but it reports `Sorry, try again.`, always.

I also tried to repair `sudo` doing:

```bsh
su
pacman -Rsn sudo
pacman -S sudo
reboot
```

Still no luck. The password is right, because `su` still works. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You are using `newname`'s password for `sudo`  rather than `root`'s, aren't you

Comment: Which password do you enter with `sudo` , the current user's or the target user's? By default, you need the current user's passwd, whereas `su` asks for the target user's. This can be changed with the `targetpw` option in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Yes, I should've read the `sudoers` file, entirely, to avoid such an issue. I was assuming it wants my root password, when I haven't configured it properly. If you provide an answer about the required steps allow anybody to use sudo with the root password, I can mark it accepted. In any case, this was the issue and with your help I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answer now to be able to mark this as answer. (I don't like unanswered questions).

I had to read the comments of the `sudoers` file. There is a toggle to switch the mode, so that I can enter the root password when using `sudo` as normal user.

Everything is explained in the `sudoers` comments.